# NGRX Unit Test 'overrideSelector' Not Working

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, ngrx

### Help Determining Why the `overrideSelector()` Method isn't Happening in Time

Ok, it appears like a timing issue, but I can't understand why this is happening.

I have an Effect that relies on a variable populated by a selector from my store. Here's my constructor for my Effects class:

```js
constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private nifiService: NifiService,
    private store: Store<NiFiState>
  ) {
    this.store.pipe(select(selectProcessingGroupTransformProcessor))
    .subscribe((p) => {this.transformProcessor = <GenericProcessor>p});
  }
```

The Selector looks like this:

##### Selector

```
export const selectProcessingGroupTransformProcessor = createSelector(
  nifiState,
  (state: NiFiState) => state.processing.processors?.filter(p => p.component.type === environment.COT_TRANSFORM_PROCESSOR_TYPE)[0]
)
```

##### Effect

```js
startTransformProcessor$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(
        ProcessingTransformActions.handleProcessingUpdateTransformSuccess
      ),
      mergeMap((action) =>{
        console.log('TRANSFORM PROC', this.transformProcessor)
        return this.nifiService
          .setProcessorState(this.transformProcessor.id, 'RUNNING')
          .pipe(
            map((resp) =>
              ProcessingTransformActions.handleStartTransformProcessorSuccess({
                processor: resp,
                gType: 'processing',
              })
            ),
            catchError((error) =>
              of(
                ProcessingTransformActions.handleStartTransformProcessorFailure(
                  { error }
                )
              )
            )
          )}
      )
    )
  );
```

Test that's failing:

##### Test

```js
it('[startTransformProcessor$] - handleProcessingUpdateTransformSuccess', () => {
        const action = handleProcessingUpdateTransformSuccess({ processor });
        const outcome = handleStartTransformProcessorSuccess({
          processor,
          gType: 'processing',
        });

        store.overrideSelector(
          selectProcessingGroupTransformProcessor,
          processor
        );
        store.refreshState();

        testScheduler.run(({ hot, cold, expectObservable }) => {
          actions$ = hot('-a', { a: action });
          const response = cold('-b|', { b: processor });
          spyObj = jest
            .spyOn(service, 'setProcessorState')
            .mockReturnValue(response);

          expectObservable(effects.startTransformProcessor$).toBe('--b', {
            b: outcome,
          });
        });
      });
```

I have another test evaluates the 'fail' condition as well immediately after the one above. Here's what I'm seeing:

When the first test runs, the `console.log()` in the Effect statement outputs `undefined`. After that, the test evaluating the 'fail/catchError' condition runs and the logging statement outputs the mocked selector. Additonally, I did have a `console.log()` statement inside the

```js
this.store.pipe(select(selectProcessingGroupTransformProcessor))
.subscribe((p) => {this.transformProcessor = <GenericProcessor>p});
```

where the variable is actually set and noticed that the logging line from the Effect being tested was output before the one in the store selector inside the class constructor.

###### Console Logging Output Order

```
console.log
    TRANSFORM PROC undefined

  console.log
    p {
      id: 'proc1',
      component: {
        id: 'proc1',
        config: { properties: [Object] },
        type: 'CoTtoNFFIProcessor'
      }
    }

  console.log
    p {
      id: 'proc1',
      component: {
        id: 'proc1',
        config: { properties: [Object] },
        type: 'CoTtoNFFIProcessor'
      }
    }

  console.log
    TRANSFORM PROC {
      id: 'proc1',
      component: {
        id: 'proc1',
        config: { properties: [Object] },
        type: 'CoTtoNFFIProcessor'
      }
    }
```

I have tried moving the `overrideSelector()` statement into a `beforeEach()`, but I get the same result. I'm using this same sort of functionality in another test suite without issue.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Subscribing in the effect constructor is not a good practice. Instead use `withLatestFrom` after `ofType`. Maybe this will also address your test failure.

Comment: @wlf Thanks for the suggestion! This appears to be a much cleaner solution and seems to have resolved my issue.